# Accidentally dropped boulder in wrong hole in the distortion world

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

In the part where you have to solve the boulder puzzle, I accidentally dropped the first boulder in to the wrong hole (the one to the left of the boulder). Is there any way I can undo this action?
I do not have a savestate from before this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave the area then come back, OR save and reload the game. Both ways the boulders will be back to their original positions.

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly speaking to one of the lake trio (Uxie, Azelf or Mesprit) nearby will reset the puzzle you are currently doing

Comment: You can't talk to any of them, because there's a rock in front of each of them. Talking to Cynthia does no good either. I ended up having to leave the area and come back :)